# No get_lod_build_settings() in unreal.EditorStaticMeshLibrary. (UE4 Python)

Tags: python, unreal-engine4

I can't find a way to get and amend the build settings on a static mesh. I'm writing a python script and running it in the Unreal editor.  (Unreal Editor version 4.25)

I have tried using the EditorStaticMeshLibrary which the docs says has the function get_lod_build_settings() but the error message comes back as if it's invalid. Can anyone see my problem or suggest another way of accessing the LOD build settings from Python? Thanks.

```
import unreal

selected_items = unreal.EditorUtilityLibrary.get_selected_assets()

print 'Num of items selected = ' + str(len(selected_items))
for item in selected_items:    
    print 'Name=' + item.get_name() + '  Class=' + item.get_class().get_name()
    num_lods = unreal.EditorStaticMeshLibrary.get_lod_count(item)
    print 'Num LODs=' + str(num_lods)       
    build_data = unreal.EditorStaticMeshLibrary.get_lod_build_settings(item, 0)
```

This is the output:

```
LogPython: Num of items selected = 1
LogPython: Name=30_06_Cartridge_SM  Class=StaticMesh
LogPython: Num LODs=1
LogPython: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
LogPython: Error:   File "C:/PL/console/HL/Content/Python/meshtest.py", line 10, in <module>
LogPython: Error:     build_data = unreal.EditorStaticMeshLibrary.get_lod_build_settings(item, 0)
LogPython: Error: AttributeError: type object 'EditorStaticMeshLibrary' has no attribute 'get_lod_build_settings'
```

Docs:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/PythonAPI/class/EditorStaticMeshLibrary.html?highlight=get_lod_build_settings#unreal.EditorStaticMeshLibrary.get_lod_build_settings

Answer (score 0):

I heard back from Epic on this and apparently this is fixed on version 4.26